# Failed to resolve import "react-dom/client" from "src\main.jsx". Does the file exist?

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors, vite

Getting This problem

```
Failed to resolve import "react-dom/client" from "src\main.jsx". Does the file exist?
```

this is my main.jsx file

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
// import {render} from "react-dom";
import App from './components/App.jsx'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

I also tried to do this

```
import React from 'react'
import {render} from "react-dom";
import App from './components/App.jsx'
import './index.css'


 const container = document.getElementById("root");
render(
 <React.StrictMode>
 <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
   container
 );
```

But this one shows blank page

please see this if someone can help

I am trying to make codepen copy project
these are my dependencies in pakage.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.31",
  "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.0",
  "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.0",
  "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.11",
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
  "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
  "codemirror": "^5.58.1",
  "react": "^16.13.1",
  "react-codemirror2": "^7.2.1",
  "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
  "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
```

Comment: What does your app structure look like?

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
import App from './components/App.jsx'
```

Write :

```
import App from './App';
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Run "npm i" it will resolve this error since a few dependencies seem to be missing when you install deps manually.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install lucide-react

npm -

```
npm install lucide-react
```

yarn -

```
yarn add lucide-react
```

pnpm -

```
pnpm install lucide-react
```

Visit - **[Official documentation](https://lucide.dev/guide/packages/lucide-react)** of lucide-react for more info